# Use a variable in SQL queries in python

Tags: python, mysql

My python script looks like this:

```
  #!/usr/bin/python
    import MySQLdb

    u='ABNCSDS7612'
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="abc",db="mydb")

    cur = db.cursor()

    sql=("insert into t1(p_id,job_id) Values ((select p_id from t2 where name='OUTPUT'),
(select job_id from job where job_uuid= "%s"))",(u))

    cur.execute(*sql)

    db.commit()
```

I am firing an insert statement where I am trying to insert 2 column values, and I want value of 2nd column from a variable in my python script  **u='ABNCSDS7612'** . I took help from a lot of similar posts but no luck.  I am still facing the error as below:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It is showing error after the brackets which occur after %s in sql. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invalid syntax error is because of the way you've put the quotes.

You actually don't need the quotes around the placeholder. And, you need to put your query parameter into a tuple. Also, I would write the query on multiple lines to improve readability:

```
sql = """
    insert into 
        t1(p_id,job_id) 
    Values 
        ((select p_id from t2 where name='OUTPUT'),
         (select job_id from job where job_uuid = %s))"""
cur.execute(sql, (u, ))
```

Comment: Might also be good to make the point that a tuple in Python with one value is `(u,)` (like you have) not `(u)` (like the OP had).

Comment: @BradK. yup, the note is there in the answer..thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

u='ABNCSDS7612'
db = MySQLdb.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
passwd="abc",
db="mydb")

cur = db.cursor()

sql="""insert into t1(p_id,job_id) Values 
((select p_id from t2 where name='OUTPUT'),
(select job_id from job where job_uuid= '%s'))""" % (u)

cur.execute(*sql)
db.commit()
```

Comment: What would happen if u would have the following value: `O'Brien`?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.